# Converting images to video format

Tags: java, image, video

I have searched a lot for Java libraries that can convert images to video format. However, I couldn't get any of them to work. So, could you suggest a library that can convert images to video format that is user friendly. And also pleas give an example of how to  use such library.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use `ffmpeg` for such a job.
Example: i got some jpg's (0001.jpg, 0002.jpg,...) in the folder c:\temp\cam. The command `ffmpeg -i c:\temp\cam\%04d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p c:\temp\cam\out.mp4` creates a mp4 file.
The documentation for that can be found here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Answer (score -1):

You can use xuggler - http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/ Xuggler is a free open-source library. You can check a tutorial here  http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/introduction-xuggler-video-manipulation.html

Answer (score -1):

> > > Try This one:: **Libav in Linux**

```
Installation: run command  
             sudo apt-get install libav-tools  

 Video conversion command::Go to folder contains the video and run in terminal  
             avconv -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi
```

where **The syntax foo-%03d.jpeg specifies to use a decimal number composed of three digits padded with zeroes to express the sequence number.**  for more [libav.org](https://libav.org/documentation/avconv.html)